# Object mode - How do I turn off visible wireframe?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, wireframe

Simple question.  I do not know but maybe I pressed a button or an option but I can still see the object wireframe in object mode.

[image]
How can I disable it to be in normal object mode as in the green part of the helmet I am working on.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple as you said. Select your object, go to the object properties panel and the make sure that wireframe isn't enabled under viewport display.[image]